# How can I shift a int by 4n times in java?

Tags: java, shift

So for example there is a function:

```
public int shift4N(int num, int n)
{
    num = num << n << n << n << n;
    return num;
}
```

Is there a less redundant way to do it? Multiplication is not allowed though...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: why do not you use for-loop?

Comment: Just to be clear though, you know that wouldn't be exactly the same thing as shifting by 4n, right? With 4 separate shifts, you can actually shift by 32 or more.

Comment: @harold Oh really? Actually I don't know that... I am a beginner on this :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A for loop seems a bit cumbersome to me, why not just replace the multiplication by a shift?

```
return num << (n << 2);
```

Comment: @ntysdd or if the function in OPs question was incorrect to begin with - it doesn't match the title or its name. Otherwise, the required modification is trivial.

Comment: Yes. In fact I noticed your comment after OP later. Anyway, others  who see this answer may not notice the tiny difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why multiplication is not allowed, is it some kind of quiz?

Then just use "num << (n << 2)" because shift is clearly allowed. (But be careful 4 * n may be greater than 32)

Comment: Thank you :) I guess it would work. Yep it is a practicing homework.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one alternative would be to use a loop,

```
public int shift4N(int num, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) num <<= n;
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic Java:

```
interface ShiftByNStrategy { int shift(int num, int n); }

final class ShiftByNOnce extends ShiftingStrategy {
    @Override public int shift(int num, int n) { return num << n; }
}

final class RepeatedShiftByNStrategy implements ShiftByNStrategy {
    private final ShiftByNStrategy strategy;
    private final int times;

    RepeatedShiftByNStrategy(ShiftByNStrategy strategy, int times) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
        this.times = times;
    }

    @Override
    public int shift(int num, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) num = strategy.shift(n);
        return num;
    }
}

final class ShiftByNStrategyFactory {
    private ShiftByNStrategyFactory() {}

    static ShiftByNStrategy shiftByNMultipleTimes(int times) {
        return new RepeatedShiftByNStrategy(new ShiftByNOnce(), times);
    }
}
```

So then you have

```
public int shift4N(int num, int n) {
    return ShiftByNStrategyFactory.shiftByNMultipleTimes(4).shift(num, n);
}
```

;)